# How to use the add_import_path Compass configuration function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to have some global partials from another compass project imported into a new compass project. I've found the add_import_path function that looks like it could be the answer.

I have defined an **add_import_path** in my config.rb but how do I import the partials in that directory?

ie:

IN CONFIG.RB

```
add_import_path "path/to/other/project/";
```

IN MY STYLE.SCSS

```
@import "grid";
@import "tyography";
@import "a partial from the other project"??
```

I can't find anything in the compass documentation on how to import from the import path. I get a compile error saying:

```
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: test.
```

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to access files from one rails app to another rails app?

Comment: Yes, so two Compass projects. But I want the second compass project to access the first project's SCSS partials and compile in with the second project. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the actual files, the filename.css.scss files from the stylesheets folder, copy them, and put them into the stylesheets folder of your new project.

You can get css files from anywhere inside your app by adding them to the top of the application.css file, the part that looks like this:

```
/* ...
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

But they should be inside your project folder somewhere.

Check out the docs here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html